# Selecting nodes between two processing instructions with XPATH

Tags: xpath

I have something like this:

```
<?cond_start condition="Online" ?>
<p>This section is tagged with Conditional "Online".</p>
<?cond_end?>

<?cond_start condition="Print" ?>
<p>This section is tagged with Conditional "Print".</p>
<?cond_end?>
```

I need to process the content between the PIs based on the value of the PIs (condition="Online" / condition="Print").
I can select a specific PI with e.g. this:

```
//processing-instruction('cond_start')
```

But I have no idea how to go beyond this … Especially not, as there can be nested PIs like this:

```
<?cond_start condition="Online" ?>
<p>This section is <?cond_start condition="Comment" ?>Are you sure?<?cond_end?> tagged with Conditional "Online".</p>
<?cond_end?>
```

Aynone any ideas?

Comment: What _exactly_ should be selected? All the `p` elements that are between `cond_start` and `cond_end` PIs? And, more importantly, are you sure this is a representative sample of your input XML? Include `p` elements that should _not_ be selected, for example, because as the input is now, a simple `//p` would work.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough ... I need to process everything between <?cond_start condition="foo" ?> and <?cond_end?>. This can be p or anything else. (Actually it's XHTML with PIs for conditional output. PIs don't have child nodes, so I need to find a way to select *everything* between two specific PIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want all nodes where

- the first preceding processing instruction node is itself a `cond_start` which has a certain contents, for example `'condition="Online"'`.
- the first following processing instruction node is itself a `cond_end`

That would be:

```
//node()[
    preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()[1][
        self::processing-instruction('cond_start')
        and contains(., 'condition="Online"')
    ]
    and following-sibling::processing-instruction()[1][
        self::processing-instruction('cond_end')
    ]
]
```

Note that this does not work when there are more processing instructions between `<?cond_start condition="..." ?>` and `<?cond_end?>`. If that's the case for you things get more complicated.

Comment: This is cool. And seems do do the trick for most cases.

It only seems to fail on some nested scenarios like this:

`code
    <?cond_start condition="Online" ?>
    <p>This sentence is tagged with one Conditional.</p>
    <?cond_start condition="Offline" ?><p>test</p><?cond_end?>
    <p>This sentence is tagged with one Conditional.</p>
    <?cond_end?>
code`

Here it also selects <?cond_start condition="Offline" ?><p>test</p><?cond_end?>.

Comment: That's what I said in the last paragraph. ;)